# Receive notification whenever someone marks email as spam POSTFIX

Tags: postfix, email-server

I have created a mail server using Postfix. I have added a 1x1 tracking pixel to track email opens.
I would like to receive a notification either on an http endpoint or my email address whenever someone marks the email as spam so that we do not send them any email again similar to AWS SES
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I doubt this is possible.  And given that mail clients by default don't load external images the tracking pixel is mostly useless.

Comment: A reputable sender adds unsubscribe links and headers.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have not subscribed to the list in the first place, the unsubscribe link might be a tracking tool in disguise, proving someone is reading the mailbox. Therefore, I never use them, but silently discard such messages. **As a decent mailing list administrator you should have opt-in subscribes instead of opt-out unsubscribes.**

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible. Postfix (or other MTA) does not take any part within this marking up process.

When the mail is delivered, it is put into MDA (message delivery agent), such as Cyrus or Dovecot. MUA (mail user agent) which is how software like Thunderbird or RoundCube (web client) is called, only interfaces this MDA when doing mail reception and reading. When user sets marks it might notify the MDA to set a "Junk" IMAP message flag, if it's using IMAP; with POP3 it can't notify even it. But MDA won't take any additional action.

The only moment when MUA interacts directly with Postfix is when Postfix takes the role of MSA (message submission agent), when user composes mail and MUA submits it for delivery.

Moreover, Thunderbird by default blocks external content loading and puts a big warning about that. So when you added a pixel image, you're showing a warning about blocked untrusted content to your recipients, rather than being able to track. As for me, this only increases chances to have the message in the "junk" folder even without reading it carefully.

To not to appear to be a spammer, you'd better:

- **opt-in** to your subscriptions rather than opt-out. Which means, you shouldn't send mail to anybody who did not explicitly requested it. All "receive our newsletter" and similar checkboxes shall be **disabled by default**. This way, people won't have to deal with the mail they did not solicited to receive.
- As suggested in the comment, include proper **unsubscribe links and headers** (`List-Unsubscribe` and so on); this will place your mail with higher score on many anti-spam systems, including Gmail, making it less probable to declare you a spammer from the very first message. Smart mail clients will show additional "unsubscribe" button, to ease user's opt-out. And you better really refrain from sending such a mail to that user, until they opt-in again.

This is not "one or another", you have to do both. Yes, you'll have much less subscribers, but you'd have only subscribers that really want your mail, which is good.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you are looking for is called **Complaint Feedback Loop**.

Many large providers, notably Microsoft and Yahoo, will let you register your IP address and/or domain to receive such notifications. You will not necessarily get a report about *each* message reported as spam. You also may not receive an additional message if the user action was *translated* into just using the unsubscribe mechanism you sent in your mail headers (you are sending it, right?). You may need to fulfil some minimum requirements of the recipient provider, and they may not give you that option if they already believe your sending practices are unreasonable in principle (and not just needing work in areas were single reports could be helpful).

But as long as you behave the way they expect you to, most of the time someone reports a message clearly tied to you as spam, they will let you know in a separate email. Expecting you do deal with the problem, of course.